# Get values of default arguments based on previous argument

Tags: php, function, default-parameters, default-arguments

I have a PHP function that takes three arguments, where one is an optional argument.

```
function theRange($min, $max) {
    // Function Body
}
```

But I have to set the limit to a default parameter and give it as an optional parameter. So, what I did is:

```
function theRange($min, $max = 5) {
    // Function Body
}
```

The problem comes when the `$min` is greater than `5` and the value becomes invalid if the maximum is lesser the the minimum value. So, I default the `$max` to `$min`, so what I did is:

```
function theRange($min, $max = $min) {
    // Function Body
}
```

This throws an error as below:

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected `'$min'` (`T_VARIABLE`) in **functions.php** on line **2**.

I am currently handling it this way:

```
function theRange($min, $max = null) {
    if (!isset($max) || is_null($max))
         $max = $min;
    // Function Body
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this default parameter, to have the previous parameter as an input scenario? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign default value, and check if it's valid inside function:

```
function theRange($min, $max = 5) {
    $max = $min > $max ? $min : $max;
}
```

Comment: If I give `theRange(10)`, that will cause an error. I wanna avoid that first line in the function body!!! :)

Comment: Well, I can't see that in your post :) Furthermore, first condition in your last example will never be true. $max is always set.

Comment: Both the answers are the same and whatever I have done is the same too! So, upvoting the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Can’t think of another way – but you could of course shorten that quite a bit using the ternary operator. And I think using `isset` makes no sense here at all – `$max` will *always* be set, *because* you specified it in the function parameters.

```
function theRange($min, $max = null) {
     $max = is_null($max) ? $min : $max;
    // Function Body
}
```

But you will still have to do additional checks anyway, because min=10 and max=5 could be passed *explicitly* to the function.

```
function theRange($min, $max = null) {
     $max = is_null($max) || $max < $min ? $min : $max;
    // Function Body
}
```

And depending on what that function is actually supposed to do, you might want to check for/exclude negative values as well …

Comment: Both the answers are the same and whatever I have done is the same too! So, upvoting the answers!